# Losing ViewModel Data after POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't see this problem too often but I've got a .cshtml that uses a layout.  In the layout I've got:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "someCssClass", @id = "UserForm" }))
{
      ...rest of the code
}
```

My main .cshtml using this layout has the model defined at the top as we always do:

```
@model CarViewModel 
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CarLayout.cshtml";
}
```

When It gets back to my action method, I get nulls for all values of the model:

```
public ActionResult Cars(CarViewModel model)
{
    carBL.RemoveCars(model.CarIds, model.DealerId);
    ...
}
```

Not sure what I need to do here and why this is happening.  Usually I just get it back successfully via autobind.  It seems to me when the model is used via RAzor in the markup- that gets posted back fine with the returned ViewModel but if I'm not using those fields, it doesn't...so I assume that's how that works and if I don't use them in mark-up I need to send them back as hidden values then to force the persistence since I  am not using x fields from the ViewModel (Which would have automatically persisted those fields if I had used them in the form)?

Comment: Well we need to see `... rest of the code` as Html.BeginForm just renders the form. What gets send to the action (and binded) is determined by elements of your form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the values are not bound to a form field, they will come back null.

in the form use the below for things like ID fields.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x...)
```

Comment: right so my assumption is that they're also bound to the form if the model values are being used in the form markup...

Comment: That would be correct. There is no "ViewState" Or anything like that. So the data needs to be in the form

Comment: Accepted answer and no upvotes? You guys are hard to please! +1 here... :)

Comment: Is there really no way to just.. generically enumerate all the hidden properties? I'm having a hard time with being responsible for every field when new fields could be added to the model, resulting in data being wiped out if the form is not kept comprehensive. Surely this is a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test, to see if the form is being posted correctly would be to modify the signature of your action:

```
public ActionResult Cars(FormCollection form)
{
    ...
}
```

If `form` is not populated then you have an issue with the form post. As a side, note you could accomplish this when reviewing the post data of the form with a tool like FireBug, Chrome Dev tools or Fiddler if you prefer.

If the form is posting correctly, then I you should check to make sure the name's of the input fields on the form align with the names of the `CarViewModel` you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been resolved yet, but this is how I do it (partial code):

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <table>
          <tr>
               <td>First Name:</td>
               <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { maxlength = "50" })
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)
               </td>
          </tr>
     </table>

     <button id="btnSave" type="submit">Save</button>
     <button id="btnCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
}
```

Then my action method to handle the HTTP post request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
     // Check for null on viewModel
     // Do what needs to be done
}
```

Doing it this way should not let you loose your values filled in on the form/view.

Comment: But this only works for the FirstName property. viewModel.LastName would be null as it isnt used in the view ?